# How do I create a method to create serial numbers based on an input parameter?

Tags: java, serialization, scope

I am creating a delimited text string from a data source that contain non-delimited document metadata. All of the data is sorted by index, then subindex, and one of the first things I want to do is create a serial number for each record. The first characters of each line dictate if this is an index or subindex record, and I use these in increment the data as noted in the logic below, which works as expected.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
 //
public class mdata
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double indexNo = 0;
        double subIndexNo = 0;
        double recNo = 0 ;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("whidata0.htm");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String inputLine = null;
            while((inputLine=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                String recordNumber = "";
                if (inputLine.trim().startsWith("aIE(2")) {
                indexNo = indexNo + 1;
                subIndexNo = .00;
                } else
                if (inputLine.trim().startsWith("aIE(3")) {
                subIndexNo = subIndexNo + .01;
                }
            recNo = indexNo + subIndexNo;
            System.out.println(recNo);
            }
        }
         //
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have other applications that require me to serialize data, and want to create a standalone method that assigns the serial number. I'm having some issues which may be scope-related, and I need an few extra set of eyes to help me understand what's happening.

Here's where I am so far with creating a serialization method:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
 //
public class mdata2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("whidata0.htm");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String inputLine = null;
            while((inputLine=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                recNo = generateSerial(inputLine.trim());
                System.out.println(recNo);
            }
        }
         //
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
     //
    public static double generateSerial(String inputLine)
    {
        double indexNo = 0;              // where do
        double subIndexNo = 0;           // these have 
        double recNo = 0 ;               // to go?

        String recordNumber = "";
        if (inputLine.trim().startsWith("aIE(2")) {
        indexNo = indexNo + 1;
        subIndexNo = .00;
        } else
        if (inputLine.trim().startsWith("aIE(3")) {
        subIndexNo = subIndexNo + .01;
        }
        recNo = indexNo + subIndexNo;
        System.out.println(recNo);
        return recNo;
    }
}
```

In the first block of code, my `recNo` prints as a sequence `1.00`,`2.00`,`2.01`,`2.02`,`2.03`,`3.00` etc. In the second, that same sequence returns as `1.00`,`1.00`,`1.01`,`1.01`,`1.01`,`1.00` etc. Looking at it, that makes sense; the first thing I'm doing in the method is resetting the variables to `0`. Initializing the variables in `main` gives me scope issues--`generateSerial` doesn't recognize the variable.

I played around with using combinations of `this.[variableName]` but that didn't seem to ave any effect. What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: I would not recommend the use of `double` values to represent -exact- quantities; doubles are approximations and there is no way to exactly represent 0.1 (or 0.01) as an IEEE floating point binary number.  If you need to use a numeric type for this purpose, you really ought to use BigDecimal which can represent exact decimal values.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.  You're not getting the output that you expected to get?  What was the output that you expected to get?

Comment: @ScottB - The first block of code, with everything in `main` is working appropriately. Once I try to use a separate method to assign a serial number, I can't figure out where to initialize my variables to duplicate those results. Different result sets are shown in the second-to-last paragraph of my post. Thanks for the tip on BigDecimal. Never heard of that...off to JavDoc land. :)

Comment: Java is an Object Oriented language.  You need to define a class that will represent the things that you're generating serial numbers for.  This class should contain a field for the serial number belonging to that object.  You can pass a reference for these objects to any method you like.  As written, your application (so far) is devoid of any object orientation at all.

Comment: That would explain a lot. I've been doing OO for about 2 years after LOTS of procedural programming. I still misfire on some of the concepts. So I was interpreting my program that the input line was an object being passed to the serialization method...which you just schooled me it ain't. Back to the JavaDoc. :)